# Outlook REST API $filter with any not registering difference between 'eq' and 'ne'

Tags: odata, outlook-restapi

I am trying to create a query that gets Outlook Contacts but excludes Contacts with an email address that contains a certain domain (let's say 'abc.com').  Here is the query I am running:

> https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts?$format=json&$filter=EmailAddresses/any(e:%20e/Address%20ne%20'abc.com')

But the response comes back as if I was using `eq` - it returns Contacts that only have emails with 'abc.com' in them.

I have tried switching out `any` with `all` because I read that `all` is used when trying to exclude items, but when I use `all` I get:
**400 Bad Request**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter",
        "message": "The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes."
    }
}
```

I have been testing using the [OAuth Sandbox](https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net) to test my queries.  Is my query incorrect? Am I using filter incorrectly?

Comment: I don't know why it is like that, but I can reproduce it in the Graph Explorer with a query like ``https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$filter=emailAddresses/any(a:a/address ne '@example.com')``. This will return a contact with e-mail address me@example.com, but not test@test.com. And changing to ``eq`` makes no difference.

Comment: The API claims you can use this to query for emails by domain, but it looks like it is literally just checking if the email address equals '@abc.com' and you probably dont have any contacts with that (invalid) email, so it basically filters nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#contact), filtering contacts using EmailAddress is not possible (Filterable? No). That is why the request does not return valid data.

Comment: Oh bummer. Thanks for the response, seems like I go down a google rabbit hole when the answer is right in the documentation.

Comment: OP's question *comes* from the documentation! They claim you should be able to do what OP is asking: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_contacts#optional-query-parameters